# Audio quality extremely bad avfoundation & soundflower

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm executing this command:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 60 -i "1:0" output.mp4
```

The video is great but audio is completely unrecognizable, only stuttering noise.

I use soundflower to use my desktop audio as input audio.

I get perfect audio if I change the last portion of my command to:

```
-i "none:0" output.mp3
```

What am I doing wrong? Do i need another video format? I've tried (avi, mp4, mkv, etc.).

Comment: I don't have macOS to be able to use avfoundation, but maybe the full log will reveal something.